# ForeignKey Very Long List

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called Director, until now I have over 200 directors.

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenth=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    director = models.ForeignKey('Director')

class Director(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('max_length=100)
```

I have a large list of directors and can not find it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you mean that you cannot "find it"?

Comment: Hello thanks, You can look at the next picture please, so you can understand my problem. http://i48.tinypic.com/50mf0i.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scalable Widget for Rendering Foreign Keys in Django Admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155937/scalable-widget-for-rendering-foreign-keys-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the raw_id field on your ModelAdmin, or http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/admin_extensions.html or even the autocomplete with http://code.google.com/p/django-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

remove quotation marks when calling the ForeignKey model

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    director = models.ForeignKey(Director)
```

Comment: The quotation marks are required because the Director model has [not yet been defined](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)